# Java Password based Encryption decrypt throwing errors

Tags: java, encryption, salt

I am trying to write a program that will encrypt a file based on a password the user enters when calling the program. The salt of the password should be included in the file. I believe the program is encrypting the file properly but when I go to decrypt the file the program throws

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Missing parameter type: IV expected.
```

I am not sure as to why this would be the case as I am not generating an IV as such. To call the program it is enc "password" fileToEncrypt.txt destinationFile.enc.

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.util.HexFormat;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FileEncryptor {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FileEncryptor.class.getSimpleName());

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String CIPHER = "AES/CBC/PkCS5PADDING";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length == 4) {
            if (args[0].equals("enc") || args[0].equals("dec")) {
                try {
                    if (args[0].equals("enc")) {
                        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
                        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec;
                        PBEParameterSpec pbeParamSpec;
                        SecretKeyFactory keyFac;

                        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
                        sr.nextBytes(salt);
                        int count = 1000;
                        pbeParamSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count);

                        char[] password = args[1].toCharArray();
                        pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password);
                        keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
                        SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
                        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
                        pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeParamSpec);
                        if (encrypt(pbeCipher, args[2], args[3],salt)) {
                            LOG.info("Encryption finished, saved at " + args[3]);
                        }
                    } else {
                        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec;
                        SecretKeyFactory keyFac;

                        char[] password = args[1].toCharArray();
                        pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password);
                        keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");
                        SecretKey pbeKey = keyFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

                        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256");

                        if (decrypt(pbeCipher, pbeKey, args[2], args[3])) {
                            LOG.info("Decryption complete, open " + args[3]);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    exceptionHandle(e);
                }
            } else {
                errorHandle("Please call encrypt or decrypt");
            }
        } else {
            errorHandle("Please call program with 4 arguments");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to encrypt a file with the Key and IV generated by the program and write the results to a
     * new file.
     *
     * @param cipher cipher generated by the program early
     * @param input  name of the file to be encrypted
     * @param output name of the new file after encryption
     * @return boolean if encryption was successful or not.
     */
    public static boolean encrypt(Cipher cipher, String input, String output,byte[] salt) {

        LOG.info("File to be Encrypted: " + input);
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(input);
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(output);
             CipherOutputStream encryptedOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(out, cipher)) {
            out.write(salt);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int nread;
            while ((nread = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                encryptedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, nread);
            }
            encryptedOutputStream.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            exceptionHandle(e);
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Method to decrypt a file with the Key inputted by the user and IV stored in the file. Then write the results to a
     * new file.
     *
     * @param cipher cipher generated by the program early based on key and IV provided.
     * @param input  name of the file to be decrypted
     * @param output name of the new file after decryption
     * @return boolean if decryption was successful or not
     */
    public static boolean decrypt(Cipher cipher,SecretKey pbeKey, String input, String output) {

        int count = 1000;
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(input);
             CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(in, cipher);
             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(output)) {
            byte[] salt = new byte[16];
            in.read(salt);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey,new PBEParameterSpec(salt, count));
            int nread;
            while ((nread = cipherInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, nread);
            }
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | InvalidKeyException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            exceptionHandle(ex);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Methods prints a message to the console to let the user know what mistakes they made when running the program.
     *
     * @param message to be printed to the console.
     */

    public static void errorHandle(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    /**
     * Program prints a message to the user to let them know what went wrong in the program based on what exception
     * was thrown early in the program and give them clear understanding of what went wrong.
     *
     * @param e Exception caught be the program
     */
    public static void exceptionHandle(Exception e) {
        if(e.getClass() == BadPaddingException.class){
            System.out.println("hello");
            LOG.info("Please input correct key. " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (e.getClass() == FileNotFoundException.class) {
            LOG.info("Please call enc or dec with an existing file. " + e.getMessage());
        }
        if (e.getClass() == InvalidKeyException.class) {
            LOG.info("Please put correct Algorithm. " + e.getMessage());
        }
        if (e.getClass() == NoSuchAlgorithmException.class) {
            LOG.info("Please put correct Cipher " + e.getMessage());
        }
        if (e.getClass() == InvalidAlgorithmParameterException.class) {
            LOG.info("Please put correct IV length. " + e.getMessage());
        }
        if (e.getClass() == IllegalArgumentException.class) {
            LOG.info("Please check length Key and IV.  " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (e.getClass() == NoSuchPaddingException.class) {
            LOG.info("Please check Padding. " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to supply an IV. Either put it into the file, unencrypted, or, simpler and better, use a fixed one that is `static` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorry I am new to this would I need to do it for both encryption and decryption because currently I didn't have to generate one for encryption?

Comment: You have to use the same one for both.

Comment: You can pass the IV as third parameter in `PBEParameterSpec` using `IvParameterSpec`. As long as the salt and thus the key are random, the IV may be static and not cause reuse of key/IV pairs (but you can also take a *random* IV and prepend it to the ciphertext like the salt, so that it is available on decryption).